# Configuring Windows Update while Desktop is Frozen with Deep Freeze

Tags: freeze

My PC went to an Endless Reboot.

The scenario was "I Thawed my computer and Download all Windows Updates after Downloading I frozen my computer with Deep Freeze and the Windows Updates was asking for a reboot to apply all changes but after the reboot a Configuring Windows Updates is doing its job and after reaching 100% it went reboot again, and Again, ang again.

Comment: try to login in safe mode and restore your computer for earlier time (before installing that windows updates)

Comment: Alright sir. Gonna Try it.

Comment: @Ayodhya, please add that as an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: @JulianKnight thanks. I have added comment as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to login in **safe mode** and **restore** your Computer to an earlier time (before installing that windows updates). It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a licensed copy of Deep Freeze, write an email to support@faronics.com and they'll provide you with the procedure to forcefully disable Deep Freeze and get you out of the boot loop.

But if you are running a crack version, then there is no way out – except for formatting your system.

And if you are running a trial version, advance your system clock to 60 days ahead which will disable Deep Freeze as well.

Good luck!